# Angular function increase every second

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create an Angular app that uses google maps and displays a radius on that map that starts at 500 and increases by 100 every second. I forked everything I need from Github and am just trying to manipulate the radius.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$scope.map.circle = {
              id: 1,
              center: center,
              radius: 500,


              //This function is not working, causes the radius to stop showing up on map
              $interval: (function(){
              $scope.map.circle.radius += 100;
               }, 1000),



              stroke: {
                  color: '#08B21F',
                  weight: 2,
                  opacity: 1
              },
```

And my HTML:

```
<ui-gmap-circle 
                center='map.circle.center'
                radius='map.circle.radius'
                fill='map.circle.fill'
                stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                editable='map.circle.editable'
                visible='map.circle.visible'
                events='map.circle.events'>
</ui-gmap-circle>
```

Everything except the function to change the radius is working.

Comment: Can you check your code for any typos once again as you are returning radius2 in the function.

Comment: when I put the code as shown in my question the page doesn't run at all, but I tried returning just 'radius' instead of 'radius2' but that did not help.

Comment: What does the `window` property expect as a parameter?

Comment: @Shomz isn't window the 'key' in the key value pair, and the value for 'setInterval' expects  an expression, time in msec, and 'language' (whatever it means by 'language' i don't know)

Comment: Yes, what value it expects? I don't see it in the docs, and it doesn't make much sense in the way you wrote it unless you use something like `clearInterval($scope.map.circle.window);` to clear the interval. But that won't change your radius.

Comment: @Shomz I think the value is the 'radius' variable that is passed in the function parameter, so it would be 500

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong there. Try removing the window property completely, and use the code I wrote you in my answer. Don't forget to inject the $interval dependency if you don't have it. Btw. `setInterval` doesn't return its return value, but just a numeric interval reference, which you can use later to clear the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the `window` property expects as a parameter (or if that's just a typo), but generally, you can change the radius directly by doing it inside an Angular interval:

```
$interval(function(){
    $scope.map.circle.radius += 100;
}, 1000);
```

By using the Angular's interval instead of native `setInterval`, you don't have to worry about scope digests.

Also, you say it should increase by 100, yet it says 10000 in your code, fix that.

Comment: Where would I post that, in html or in the js? I tried using that in the js but then when i ran the web page the map doesn't show up

Comment: That goes inside your controller, it's hard to tell without seeing the whole thing, but you're probably getting errors if you didn't inject the $interval dependency (like you did $scope, for example). Check your console for errors.

Comment: I inserted it right underneath where radius is first defined. I am not getting any errors but the radius still isn't expanding

Comment: I will update my code in this question and upload a link where i will post the entire website. If I am able to put a bounty giving all my 29 XP i will do that lol because I would like to show this in an interview i have tomorrow if possible

Comment: Haha, don't worry about the bounty, save your points until you gather some more. :) I'll probably leave very soon, but I'm sure you'll be able to work this out.

Comment: OK haha thanks for the help. I think so I feel like it's close

Comment: Still no luck, here is the link if you or anyone else is interested: alainwebdesign.ca/dogfinder/example/issue-1068-circle-events-doubled.html

Comment: You have an error in the console, and also I don't see the code I gave you in the controller.

Comment: YESSS that is exactly what i wanted and just in time!!!!! I leave for my interview in 20 minutes. I can't thank you enough, if there's anything I can do for you please let me know. Thanks again :D

Comment: Haha, no worries, I'm glad I could help! Good luck with the interview! :)

Comment: I got the Job! Thanks @Shomz, really appreciate it

Comment: CONGRATULATIONS!!!  Then this is also my biggest achievement on Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, you occasionally have to substitute methods with their angular counter-parts for it to work properly.  Replace `window.setInterval()` with `$interval()`.  The params are passed in the same order.